# .htaccess mod_rewrite with final slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works allright if i end all my urls with `/`. For example `http://localhost/test/test2/test3/`.
But if I forget to put / in the end, I get not found error... I've tried to tweak this rewrite rule but cant make it work both ways (with and without final /).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it optional with the `?` operator:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ foo.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

... or simply remove completely, since you don't seem to need it at all:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foo.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

... or even:

```
RewriteRule ^ foo.php?action=$0 [QSA,L]
```